# What is the meaning of free energy out of equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

So in statistical mechanics the free energy $F$ (either canonical or grand canonical) can be found from the partition sum $\mathcal{Z}$ as:
$$
\mathcal{Z}=\exp(-\beta F).
$$
As far as I can read it makes no sense to define a partition sum out of equilibrium and hence no sense to talk about a free energy.

> My questions are:
>
> 1. Why doesn't it make sense to define a partition sum out of equilibrium?
> 2. Why should a free energy be meaningless out of equilibrium?

Comment: You can kind of think of it as the deviation from the maximum entropy state of the system.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Are you aiming at the interpretation of the free energy as the "amount of work a system can perform" type of energy?

Comment: Kind of but not exactly.  Imagine one had a particle velocity distribution function that had non-Maxwellian features.  The energy associated with the non-Maxwellian features is not necessarily enough to return the system back to an isotropic Maxwellian.  It can get close, but not all the way.  In a plasma, this is done through an instability which radiates an electromagnetic wave that removes free energy from the distribution.